# Does Word2Vec has a hidden layer?

Tags: neural-network, word2vec

When I am reading one of papers of Tomas Mikolov: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf

I have one concern on the Continuous Bag-of-Words Model section：

> The first proposed architecture is similar to the feedforward NNLM, where the non-linear hidden layer is removed and the projection layer is shared for all words (not just the projection matrix); thus, all words get projected into the same position (their vectors are averaged).

I find some people mention that there is a hidden layer in Word2Vec model, but from my understanding, there is only one projection layer in that model. Does this projection layer do the same work as hidden layer?

The another question is that how to project input data into the projection layer?

"the projection layer is shared for all words (not just the projection matrix)", what does that mean?

Comment: see this [similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140377/question-about-continuous-bag-of-words) on Cross Validated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [original paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf), section 3.1, it is clear that there is no hidden layer:

> "the first proposed architecture is similar to the feedforward NNLM
>   where the non-linear hidden layer is removed and the projection layer is shared for all words".

With respect to your second question (what does sharing the projection layer means), it means that you consider only one single vector, which is the centroid of the vectors of all the words in context. Thus, instead of having `n-1` word vectors as input, you consider only one vector. This is why it is called Continuous **Bag of Words** (because word order is lost within the context of size `n-1`).

Comment: Yes, that's why I am confused that some paper mentioned there is a hidden layer in Word2Vec. In my opinion, there is a projection layer instead of a hidden layer inside the Word2Vec model

Comment: @Fox I think you should trust the original paper... You can also have a look at the Python [code](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py)

Comment: Thanks, Antoine. I want to make sure that there is no need to have n-1 word vectors as input, I only need to deal with one word vector (CBOW bagging words into one word vector), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You have as your input a V-dimensional one-hot vector (V being the vocabulary size, i.e. the number of unique words) where you have a 1 for each context word and 0 elsewhere. What it does is that it selects the rows of the VxM input->projection weight matrix (each row of this matrix is one word vector, the representation of the word in the lower-dimensional feature space of length M<<V) and averages them so that each neuron of the projection layer of dimension M,1 is the element-wise average of the context word vectors

Comment: Does this imply a hidden layer is called hidden layer because it has non linear activation applied? Otherwise why can't we interpret the projection layer in word2vec models as a hidden layer?

Comment: yes, exactly. As far as I understand, the convention is that a layer is called hidden when it applies a nonlinear transformation. This is why in word2vec, the layer is just called projection layer.